# Converting Decimal BGR color to individual RGB decimal values

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fullcalendar

I have a database table which is storing color values as a BGR (blue, green, red), and for use in full calendar need to have them formated in a RGB(decimal, decimal, decimal) string.  Is there a better way then converting to hex, then splitting, then back to decimal?

example BGR color: 13369599

`color = ("%06x" % 13369599).to_s.split(/(..)(..)(..)/)`

`=> ["", "cc", "00", "ff"]`

`rgb_value = "rgb( " << color[3].hex.to_s << "," << color[2].hex.to_s << "," << color[1].hex.to_s << ");"`

desired output

`rgb_value =  rgb( 255,00,204);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of my first languages was C, and the following would be a fairly trivial macro.

```
color = ((color & 0xff0000) >> 16) | (color & 0x00ff00) | ((color & 0x0000ff) << 16)
```

Put this inside a `bgr_to_rgb` method and forget about it. There is no need to reach for `#to_s` or `#hex`.

To get the individual R, G, B values from a BGR code, use

```
red = color & 0x0000ff
green = color & 0x00ff00
blue = color & 0xff0000
```

Comment: that works to get a RGB decimal value, but what i'm ultimately looking for are the individual RGB values.

Comment: Then don't OR them togther. See example.